# ProgressDialog freezes while retrieve data from Firebase/Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, progressdialog

I use MVP. I both show and dismiss progress dialog in view, and retrieve data from firebase/firestore in presenter, using Callback to pass data to view.

But the progress dialog freezes in UI when loading data.
Is there any method to make progress dialog keep spinning when getting data from firebase/firestore?

show dialog in view:

```
progressDialog = Utils.showProgressDialog(getContext(), getString(R.string.progress_msg_loading));
menuListPresenter.getMenuList(currentStore.getId());
```

load data in presenter:

```
@Override
public void getMenuList(String companyId) {
    this.companyId = companyId;
    if (Utils.isNullOrEmpty(companyId)) {
        view.onError(Constants.EMPTY_FIRESTORE_RESULT);
    } else {
        DocSnippets.getInstance().listenProductStatus(companyId, this);
    }
}
```

pass data to view in presenter:

```
@Override
public void onProductStatusChanged(ArrayList<Product> products) {
    if (products != null && products.size() > 0) {
        view.menuOnChanged(products);
    }
}
```

dismiss dialog in view:

```
@Override
public void menuOnChanged(ArrayList<Product> products) {
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) progressDialog.dismiss();
    // other code
}
```

Comment: Kindly add your code to expect answer to your question.

Comment: Load data in another Thread

Comment: @PradyumanDixit I added my code

Comment: @kate What kind of adapter are you using?

Comment: @AlexMamo ArrayAdapter<T>, and I use se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.ExpandableStickyListHeadersListView, a library, so the adapter implements StickyListHeadersAdapter

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a back ground thread in presenter, while processing the result.

And you should use `runOnUiThread()` method on view side updates sent by presenter. This is only the way that is suggested for this.

Comment: I use  AsyncTask.execute to start a background thread in presenter, and Handler to show/dismiss progress dialog in UI thread in view, the progress dialog still freeze. But the speed seems to be faster